# importHref on edge/safari resulting in 'A custom element with name 'dom-bind' has already been defined

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polyfills

I've been having issues with errors on importHref in Polymer (polymer-2) in edge and safari , On the initial load I get a whole series of errors like..

> SCRIPT5022: A custom element with name 'dom-bind' has already been
>   defined. webcomponents-lite.js (168,225)
>
> SCRIPT5022: A custom element with name 'dom-repeat' has already been
>   defined. webcomponents-lite.js (168,225)
>
> SCRIPT5022: A custom element with name 'dom-if' has already been
>   defined. webcomponents-lite.js (168,225)
>
> SCRIPT5022: A custom element with name 'array-selector' has already
>   been defined. webcomponents-lite.js (168,225)
>
> SCRIPT5022: A custom element with name 'iron-location' has already
>   been defined. webcomponents-lite.js (168,225)
>
> SCRIPT5022: A custom element with name 'iron-query-params' has
>   already been defined.

..
A side result of this is that none of the iron-icons in my site load, bar that however the site loads fine and is functional.
Interestingly if I just refresh the page all the errors are gone and the iron-icons display correctly..

My site is build with the following polymer.json

```
{
  "entrypoint": "src/index.html",
  "shell": "src/my-app/my-app.html",
  "fragments": [
    "src/my-view/my-view.html"
  ],
  "sources": [
    "src/images/*"
  ],
  "extraDependencies": [
  ],
  "lint": {
    "rules": ["polymer-2"]
  },
  "builds": [{
    "name": "myapp",
    "preset": "es5-bundled",
    "bundle": {
      "inlineCss":false,
      "inlineScripts":true,
      "stripComments":true
    }
  }]
}
```

index.html

```html
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js" defer></script>

<script>
     // Load webcomponentsjs polyfill if browser does not support native Web Components
    (function() {
        //'use strict';
        var onload = function() {
            console.log("webcomponents supported.");
            if (!window.HTMLImports) {
                console.log("dispatch event webcomponents ready");
                document.dispatchEvent(
                    new CustomEvent('WebComponentsReady', {
                    bubbles: true
                    })
                );
            }
        };
        var webComponentsSupported = (
            'registerElement' in document &&
            'import' in document.createElement('link') &&
            'content' in document.createElement('template')
        );
        if (!webComponentsSupported) {
            console.log("BROWSER DOES NOT SUPPORT WEB COMPONENTS");
            console.log(" = LOADING POLYFILL");

            window.Polymer = {
                dom: 'shadow',
                lazyRegister: true
            };
      } else {
            var esa = document.createElement('script');
            esa.src = '/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js';
            esa.onload = function() {
                console.log('on load custom elements es5');
            }
            document.head.appendChild(esa);
      }
    })();
  </script>
```

- Then if I try to import my-view as below I get the errors ..

> Polymer.importHref(this.resolveUrl('../my-view/my-view.html'), null,
>   null, true);

It doesn't matter what polymer file I try to import it will always kick the same error, even if there are no imports ,  inside my-view.. Am I using fragments wrong? Or any idea why this is happening.

The issue is not reproducible if I just link my-view directly in with   
nor is it reproducible in chrome, so seems like a webcomponents polyfil problem

Comment: Why do you want to use asynchronously with the defer attribute?

Answer (score 0):

When loaded asychronously with the defer attribute, polyfill bundles will be loaded asynchronously, which means that scripts and modules that depend on webcomponents APIs must be loaded using WebComponents.waitFor function.

The WebComponents.waitFor function takes a callback function as an argument, and will evaluate that callback after the polyfill bundle has been loaded.

The callback function should load scripts that need the polyfills, here example:

```
<!-- Load polyfills; note that "loader" will load these async -->
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js" defer></script>

<!-- Load a custom element definitions in `waitFor` and return a promise -->
<script type="module">
  WebComponents.waitFor(() => {
    // At this point we are guaranteed that all required polyfills have
    // loaded, and can use web components API's.
    // The standard pattern is to load element definitions that call
    // `customElements.define` here.
    // Note: returning the import's promise causes the custom elements
    // polyfill to wait until all definitions are loaded and then upgrade
    // the document in one batch, for better performance.

    // Here dynamically loading the html (Outside of Polymer) 
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.setAttribute('rel', 'import');
    link.setAttribute('href', 'my-view.html');
    link.onload = function() {
           return document.body.appendChild(link);
    }
  });
</script>

<!-- Use the custom element -->
<my-view></my-view>
```

[HERE](https://github.com/WebComponents/webcomponentsjs) THE FULL ARTICLE FOR THE ABOVE

Inside the polymer, importing HTML dynamically example:

```
Polymer.import( ['my-view.html'], ()=> {
      // called when our import is fully loaded
      // including any assets like CSS.
});
```

Comment: Thanks HakanC . If I use WebComponents.waitFor(() with defer it always returns WebComponents is not defined. If I remove defer it works and the page loads in chrome. In safari it seems to import successfully but my-view never gets displayed. In my initial configuration with the custom listener it all works fine except the errors from importHref inside my-view

Comment: @CormacGuerin Then pls try `window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', ()=>{` instead of `WebComponents.waitFor(() => {`